# Can't config certificate-based authentication in WinRM / WSMan

Tags: authentication, winrm

I'm trying to configure certificate-based authentication in WinRM. I need this to source-initiated subscription of WEF from non-domain machine.
I use manual published by MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/setting-up-a-source-initiated-subscription
My environment - I have 2 servers:

- **wef01.mydomain.local** (this is machine which will send events; it is not joined to AD)
- **wec01.mydomain.local** (this is my Events Collector; it is joined to AD)

Both machines runs Windows Server 2019 std. I also have own PKI:

- **RootCA.mydomain.local**
- **IssuingCA.mydomain.local**
  I have configured WinRM on **wef01** and **wec01**
  I have created local user account on **wec01** machine named *wef01*. For debugging purposes I added this user to local Administrators group. I've checked that I can login (interactively i through RDP) to **wec01** using this account.
  On server **wec01** I've mapped certificate issued for machine **wef01** to local account *wef01*:

```
$UserName = 'wef01'
$UserPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '*********' -AsPlainText -Force)
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $UserPassword
$params = @{
    Path = 'WSMan:\localhost\ClientCertificate'
    Subject = "wef01.mydomain.local"
    URI = '*'
    Issuer = "716A23DA41C9CF0DB9F5D35E2CF187A5A53F844F" #My PKI RootCA Cert thumbprint
    Credential = $credential
    Force = $true
}
New-Item @params
```

After all configuration staeps I checked whether I can open WinRM session using username/password authentication:

```
$UserName = 'wef01'
$UserPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '*********' -AsPlainText -Force)
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $UserPassword
Enter-PSSession wec01.mydomain.local -UseSSL -Credential $credential
[wec01.mydomain.local]: PS C:\Users\wef01\Documents>
```

Yes, I can, but attempt with certificate-based authentication failed:

```
Enter-PSSession wec01.mydomain.local -UseSSL -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint 
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server wec01.mydomain.local failed with the following error message : WS-Management cannot process the request. The operation failed because of an HTTP error. The HTTP error (12186) is: The client certificate credentials were not recognized. . For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession wec01.mydomain.local -UseSSL -CertificateThumbprint ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (wec01.mydomain.local:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

$Thumbprint variable contains thumbprint of certificate issued for wef01 machine for purpose of authentication. This certificate is installed in LocalMachine\my store, has EnhancedKeyUsage set to *Client Authentication* and subjectAltName set to *DNS Name=wec01.mydomain.local*
I checked many other websites about configuring certificate-based authentication in WinRM but I didn't find solution.
Have anybody an idea what I did wrong?
Best regards
Lukid

Comment: I don't see anything about the steps performed for validating the root/intermediate CA on the client, and also the validation of the certificate revocation list from the client. What has been done for that?  "Verify that both the server and client are able to successfully check revocation status on all certificates."

Comment: @GregAskew You are right - source of problem was CRLs validation - after I changed CDPs and AIAs to http-based only (it was LDAP-based) and made sure (Test-Certificate) that certificate validation works correctly my problem disappeared